# How to pass state between these 2 components

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I am trying to conditionally render a functional component. I have another component for the layout of the page. It contains a list item which the user will click to show this other component. Ideally, I'm hoping to have a few of these.

I have tried just about every example I can find online. Callback functions, using the React docs etc. I'm only trying to toggle a Boolean value to show a component or not. So using Redux seems a bit extreme for what I'm trying to do. I'm not sure if it has to do with this being a next, or typescript project.

Here is the parent component - index.tsx

```
 const Index: React.FC = ({flagHelper}: any) => {
  const handleOpenLink = (href: string) => {
    window.open(href);
    return false;
  };
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <Layout>
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <div className={classes.background}>
        </div>
        <Head>
          <title>Countryball Creator</title>
        </Head>
        <div className={classes.strip}>
        {flagHelper && (<div>hello</div>)}
        
        </div>
      </div>
    </Layout>
  );
};

export default Index;
```

And here is the layout/child component.

```
export const Layout: React.FC<LayoutProps> = (props) => {
  const { container } = props;
  const classes = useStyles();
  const theme = useTheme();
  const [mobileOpen, setMobileOpen] = React.useState(false);

  function handleDrawerToggle() {
    setMobileOpen(!mobileOpen);
  }


// Set state for component
const [flagHelper, setFlagHelper] = useState(false); // Flag tool

  const drawer = (
    <div>
      <div className={classes.toolbar} />
      <Divider />
      <List>
        {['Pick Flag'].map((text) => (
          <ListItem button key={text} onClick={() => setFlagHelper(!flagHelper)} className={classes.menuItem}>
            <ListItemIcon className={classes.menuItem}><DashboardIcon /></ListItemIcon>
            <ListItemText primary={text} />
          </ListItem>
        ))}
      </List>
    </div>
  );
  

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <CssBaseline />
      <AppBar position="fixed" className={classes.appBar}>
        <Toolbar>
          <IconButton
            color="inherit"
            aria-label="open drawer"
            edge="start"
            onClick={handleDrawerToggle}
            className={classes.menuButton}
          >
            <MenuIcon />
          </IconButton>
          <Typography variant="h6" noWrap>
            Countryball Creator 
          </Typography>
          <User/>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
      <nav className={classes.drawer} aria-label="mailbox folders">
        {/* The implementation can be swapped with js to avoid SEO duplication of links. */}
        <Hidden smUp implementation="css">
          <Drawer // this one is for mobile
            container={container}
            variant="temporary"
            anchor={theme.direction === 'rtl' ? 'right' : 'left'}
            open={mobileOpen}
            onClose={handleDrawerToggle}
            classes={{
              paper: classes.drawerPaper,
            }}
            ModalProps={{
              keepMounted: true, // Better open performance on mobile.
            }}
          >
            {drawer}
          </Drawer>
        </Hidden>
        
        <Hidden xsDown implementation="css">
          <Drawer // This one is for desktop
            classes={{
              paper: classes.drawerPaper,
            }}
            variant="permanent"
            open
          >
            {drawer}
          </Drawer>
        </Hidden>
      </nav>
      <main className={classes.content}>
        <div className={classes.toolbar} />
        {props.children}
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Which component should be displayed conditionally and based on what condition?

Comment: If `Index` needs `flagHelper` it should be located there, and then pass the value and setter down to `Layout` as props.

Comment: Yup this is a classic case for [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html). flagHelper should be a state for Index and a prop for Layout — you’ve got it backwards.